# Settings in CMakeLists.txt that populate CMakeSettings.json

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

In our current product uses CMakeLists.txt for the multiple applications that are built on a RHEL.  I know you can use Visual Studio 2017 (v15.5) to read these files, edit, build, and debug on a remote RHEL machine.  VS2017 creates a CMakeSetings.json on where to place the remote file(s), build information, ...

My question is:

1. If this is even possible.
2. Is there documentation on how to configure the CMakeLists.txt file that populates the CMakeSettings.json?
3. If so, where can I find the documentation on how this is done?

Thanks.